# Isn't this code redundant taking into account C++ memory management?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, io

I'm a C++ newbie, so I don't truly understand how C++ manages memory. Isn't this code redundant?

```cpp
void processData()
{
    FILE* savedDataFile;
    char* savedData;
    try {
        savedDataFile = fopen("../savedData.dump", "r");
        if (!savedDataFile)
            throw 0;
        savedData = (char*)malloc(0xf000);
        fread(savedData, 1, 0xf000, savedDataFile);
        fclose(savedDataFile);
        free(savedDataFile); // Do I really need this?
    }
    catch (int e) {
        try {
            fclose(savedDataFile); // Do I really need this?
        }
        catch (int e) {
        }
        free(savedDataFile); // Do I really need this?
        free(savedData); // Do I really need this?
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load saved data from the previous dump.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Data processing... it may take a while.
    free(savedData); // Do I really need this? Taking into account that this's actually the end of the program, there's only returning of EXIT_SUCCESS in the main function after it.
}

int main()
{
    // Some work... then the last function's called:
    processData();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I really don't like redundant code, so I want to make my code free from it. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Read the documentation of the function used for allocating the according resource carefully! It is documented in there. BTW: That code is horrible on many levels. Consider submitting it for review at codereview.stackexchange.com, read the site guidelines there though.

Comment: In C++ you shouldn't use `malloc` and `free`, nor `fopen` or `fclose`. Or, generally speaking, pointers.

Comment: The `free(savedDataFile);` lines are not just unnecessary, they're plain **wrong**.

Comment: This is not code written to utilize common idioms. It's more like what you'd get from a developer who thinks their C and Java knowledge is enough to get by in C++.

Comment: Actually... I don't think whomever wrote this grasps C well either.

Comment: This code is, to put it simply, junk. That's all you need to know about it.

Comment: This code **isn't using** any of C++'s memory management features. So yes, it does need to free and fclose everything.

Comment: @user253751 But *not* `free(savedDataFile)`

Comment: *their C and Java knowledge is enough to get by in C++* Been there done that. Still finding and cleaning up bits of code from the couple years I laboured under that delusion. I was saved by someone giving me a copy of Effective C++ for Christmas.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You're right, I'm not experienced in C++ or even C but suddenly have to use it now, that's why understanding of these details is that important for me.

Comment: So you need to learn C++ quickly. I understand that. Not really possible but understandable. But learning from *this* code is probably the worst thing you could imagine. If this code is typical of the system you need to work *with*, well then, you are up a s**t creek without a paddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `FILE*` pointer that is `fopen()`'d must be `fclose()`'d. Any dynamic memory that is `malloc()`'d must be `free()`'d.

So yes, *in general*, you need those calls, *BUT* only when used correctly!  Which this code is not doing.

If `fopen()` fails, an `int` is thrown, and then the exception handler is exhibiting all kinds of bad/illegal behavior because it is:

- using a secondary `try..catch` that will never be triggered.
- calling `fclose()` on a NULL `FILE*`, which is *undefined behavior*.
- calling `free()` on a NULL `FILE*`, which is OK in this case only because `free(NULL)` is *well-defined behavior*, but is *wrong* in general since `FILE*` pointers are not guaranteed to be `malloc()`'d to begin with.  The actual allocation used is a private implementation detail of `fopen()`, and `fclose()` will handle the deallocation appropriately.
- calling `free()` on an *uninitialized* `char*` pointer, which is *undefined behavior*.

Even if `fopen()` were successful, there are still problems, as the code is:

- not checking to make sure that `malloc()` is successful before passing the `char*` pointer to `fread()`.
- calling `free()` on a `FILE*` pointer after `fclose()`'ing the same pointer.

The correct code *could* look more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int processData()
{
    FILE* savedDataFile;
    char* savedData;
    size_t savedDataSize;

    try {
        savedDataFile = fopen("../savedData.dump", "r");
        if (!savedDataFile)
            throw 0; // jumps to the 'catch' that exits the function, nothing to free or close...
        try {
            savedData = (char*)malloc(0xf000);
            if (!savedData)
                throw 1; // jumps to the 'catch' that closes the file, nothing to free...
            try {
                savedDataSize = fread(savedData, 1, 0xf000, savedDataFile);
                if (ferror(savedDataFile))
                    throw 2; // jumps to the 'catch' that frees the memory...
            }
            catch (int) {
                free(savedData);
                throw; // jumps to the 'catch' that closes the file...
            }
        }
        catch (int) {
            fclose(savedDataFile);
            throw; // jumps to the 'catch' that exits the function...
        }
    }
    catch (int) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load saved data from the previous dump.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(savedDataFile);

    // Data processing... it may take a while.

    free(savedData);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
    // Some work... then the last function's called:
    return processData();
}
```

Which is obviously quite ugly and error-prone.  You can greatly clean this up by using C++ semantics instead of C semantics, letting the compiler and standard library handle all of the memory management and cleanup for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

int processData()
{
    std::vector<char> savedData;

    try {
        std::ifstream savedDataFile;
        savedDataFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit); // tell the stream to throw if something fails...

        savedDataFile.open("../savedData.dump"); // throws if fails to open the file...

        savedData.resize(0xf000); // throws if fails to allocate memory...

        std::streamsize numRead = savedDataFile.readsome(savedData.data(), savedData.size()); // throws if fails to read from the file...

        savedData.resize(numRead); // may shrink the size, but won't throw...
    } // <-- file is closed here
    catch (const std::exception &) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load saved data from the previous dump.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Data processing... it may take a while.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // <-- vector memory is freed here on return

int main()
{
    // Some work... then the last function's called:
    return processData();
}
```

Comment: @Hari please stop making edits to my answer. I reject them because they are wrong, introducing incorrect logic and breaking the intent of my code.  I have updated my examples to explain what they are doing.

Comment: point noted. Your updated answer looks good.

Comment: Hmm, well, it's even more complicated than I thought, so thank you for this variant of this code, it may be useful for my work. Guess, it would be perfect for me to go deeper into this theme and not to think about some simple solution naïvely.